# SWIG: custom types in structures and assignment in python

Tags: python, c++, swig

My C++ code has something like this:

```
struct Data
{
    CustomType member;
};
```

My swig .i file has %typemap(in) and %typemap(out) to convert Python strings to and from CustomType (this is working fine for parameters and return values)

In my python, I do this:

```
d = Data()
d.member = "Hello"
```

And python gives me this error at run time:
TypeError: in method 'Data_member_set', argument 2 of type 'CustomType *'

I tried the following to no effect:

```
%typemap(memberin) CustomType
{
    $target = *$source;
}
```

How do allow python to let me assign to that member?

Answer (score 0):

If a `CustomType` can be created from a string, you should be able to do

```
d.member = CustomType("Hello")
```

If that fails then you haven't exported `CustomType` via the .i file, or it doesn't have a constructor that takes a string.

Comment: This solution does not work for me because CustomType is not exposed to python - in python we use the python str type exclusively. replacing CustomType(...) with str(...) doesn't work.

Comment: @njaard Then how do you expect to be able to assign to it?

Comment: I expect it to convert from a python str just as it would when I pass the str as a parameter to a function accepting CustomType

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something like this:

```
%typemap(in) CustomType* (CustomType tmp, int res)
// or even: %typemap(in) CustomType* ($*1_type tmp, int res)
{
  if (PyString_Check($input))
  {
    tmp = (PyString_AsString($input));
    $1 = &tmp;
  }
  else
  {
    res = SWIG_ConvertPtr($input, (void **) &$1,$1_descriptor, 0 |  0 );
    if (!SWIG_IsOK(res)) {
      SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res), "in method '" "$symname" "', argument " "$argnum"" of type '" "$1_type""'.\n"
        "  Possible argument types are: 'string' and '" "$*1_type" "'\n");
    }
  }
}
```

This means the following:

1. Python does not allow you to override an assignemet operator. Instead
       of that SWIG generates wrapper functions for all possible assignments in your
       C++ code. In every place where an "= " could
       be it injects the call of the wrapper fuction.
2. With the above 'typemap' you make possible to initialize an object
   of CustomType from a) CustomType and b) built-in Pyton
       string.
3. The code within 'typemap' is just a fragment of the code of the
   wrapper finction being generated by SWIG.
4. You define a local variable of CustomType in the wrapper function.
   The code in round paranthesis in the first line are local
       variables wich scope is the whole function.

And I suggest you to open *_pywrap.cxx file (the one is generated by SWIG) and check what it actually generates based on your 'typemap'.

For more details, consult with the oficial documentation: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGDocumentation.html